# Optimized way to access posted form data - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, httpserver

In one of the older project I saw two types of handling of form data.
In one of the method it is done using `EventEmitter` methods like this:

```
 http.createServer(function(req, res){
       let decoder = new StringDecoder("utf-8");
       let buffer="";
        req.on("data", fuction(chunk){
            buffer += decoder.write(chunk);
        })
       });

       req.on("end", function(chunk){
                    // Logic
       });
 });
```

Second way(Express Way) of doing this is getting params from request's body.

```
  app.post('/',function(req, res){
       const name = req.body.name;
    
    });
```

As far as I am understanding if posted data is less in size we can use Body to fetch data and if posted data is large we can switch to Buffer.

Is there any other good explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Express is just a lib that wraps around the vanilla HTTP lib. If you read the expressjs source code, it's still the Node HTTP lib under the hood. When the body is too big, streams can be use to write data continuously and effectively.